# Why my query delete more one row using 'WHERE IN' clause?

Tags: sql-server

So, let's say that I have this `table1`

```
 StorageID | UserID 
-----------+-------
    aaa    |   7
    aab    |   7
    aac    |   7
    bbb    |   9
    bbc    |   9
    ccc    |   11
    ccd    |   11
    cce    |   11
    ddd    |   12
    dde    |   12
```

I want to delete data, so each `userID` can only get one `storageID`.

I've try this query

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE UserID IN ('7', '9', '11', '12') 
  AND StorageID IN ('aab', 'aac', 'bbc', 'ccd', 'cce', 'dde')
```

But it's return to delete 7 rows it's should be 6 rows deleted.

Is there any wrong with my query?

Comment: And what storageID should remain?

Comment: @juergend it should be StorageID 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd' and UserID '7', '9', '11', '12'

Comment: And why - the DB needs a rule to determine the result

Comment: Run the same command as a select, and you see what happens. The problem is most likely somewhere not shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The inner select gets all records that should stay. Join to that and delete all where the join could not be made.

```
delete t1
from table1 t1
left join 
(
  select userId, min(storageId) as minstorage
  from table1
  group by userId
) t2 on t1.userId = t2.userId and t1.storageId = t2.minstorage
where t2.userId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are telling to SQL:

```
DELETE ALL RECORDS WHERE UserID IN ('7', '9', '11', '12') 
AND 
DELETE ALL RECORDS WHERE StorageID IN ('aab', 'aac', 'bbc', 'ccd', 'cce', 'dde')
```

You must explicitly tell which pairs must be deleted:

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE 
     (UserID = '7' AND StorageID = 'aab')
     OR
     (UserID = '7' AND StorageID = 'aab')
     OR
     ....
     ....
```